# How to sort Safari Bookmark Folders in MacOS Catalina 10.15?

Tags: safari, bookmarks

I have lots of saved bookmarks in Safari (v15) on my MacBook, and each is saved in a specific bookmark folder. Thus I have lots of bookmark folders, and I would like to sort the folders alphabetically—how to do this? There seems to be no functionality to do this through the Safari GUI, however you can easily sort individual bookmarks inside a folder.  Can anyone help me? Screen shot of unsorted folders below.

I understand the SafariSort utility is no longer available, and the http://www.safarisort.com URL doesn’t work anymore.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: James, I've just written a utility that does this. PM me if you are interested. Mark

Comment: Why not export the bookmarks and sort the structured text file? Also, you might be a perfect candidate for a tagging service like https://pinboard.in/faq/#general due to your strong organization efforts here and volume of bookmarks.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new bookmark folder named *tmp*.
2. Drag all of your top level bookmarks folders to the new *tmp* folder.
3. Right click on *tmp* folder and hit **Sort By**.
4. Extract all folders from *tmp* and delete *tmp*.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark folders sort manually, I'm afraid.
Drag & drop to change the order - be careful you don't drop one folder inside another, it's easy to do. Folders are sprung, so if you hover too long, they'll open.

[image]

Comment: I am surprised that such a basic and sought-after function doesn't exist in Safari..

Comment: tbh, it's not a feature I've looked for in 30 years of internet browsing. I guess horses for courses.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them by going to the Bookmarks menu and choosing Show Bookmarks.

Then you right click on the list of bookmarks and folders. Go down to Sort-By and choose Name.

You can do this for each folder you want sorted as well.

Comment: How do you successfully right-click on a list of folders after Show Bookmarks and get the Sort By option? When you do that, all selected folders get deselected and the context menu appears with only the folder right-click's location coincides with being selected (Ventura).